# Trouble in understanding the simplification of log-likelihood function

Tags: linear-algebra, log-likelihood

I am having trouble to understand the simplification of this log-likelihood function. 
$$ \tag{1} \sum[ y \log{\left(p(W_TX) \right)} + (1-y)\log(1-p(W_TX)) ] $$

$$ \tag{2} \sum [ y \frac{ \log (p(W_TX) }{ 1-p(W_T X))} + \log \left(\frac{ 1 }{ 1 + e ^{W_T X}} \right) $$

$$ \tag{3}  \sum [ y w x -\log\left(1 + e ^{W_T X} \right) ] $$
Where,

$W_T$ = Weights transpose of the equation

$X$ = Input variables

$y$ is the output(0 or 1)

As there are three steps in reaching the function's simplified version, I am unable to understand the transition from 2nd to 3rd step or rather 1st to 3rd step. Also I find 1st equation to result a different answer from 3rd on solving an example.
[Log_likelihood Formula Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7y0F.png)
(Kindly Refer the image for the formula, apologies for uploading an image instead of math function)
The source of the image is from the following Slides
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~guestrin/Class/10701-S05/slides/LogRegress-1-24-05.pdf

Kindly help by breaking the equation even further(a basic logarithmic transformation that I am not able to figure out).
Thanks in advance

---

**EDIT**

> Also I find 1st equation to result a different answer from 3rd on solving an example.

**Checking again with an example(given below) the equations (1) and (3) return the same values**
So, they are **equal**.But I still don't get the logarithmic transformation from (1) to (3)

y = 0
W = [-2.9469674,    0.03791044,     0.01467374]
X = [1,         34.623659624517,    78.0246928153624]
z = WTX = -0.489455173271831
h = sigmoid(z) = 0.380021923306988
log(h) = -0.9675
log(1- h) = -0.478

(3)
**y *     z  - log(1 + e^z)**
0 * -0.489 - log(1+ e^-0.489)  = -0.47824416197

(1)
**y *  log(h)+(1-y) * log(1-h)**
0 * -0.967 + 1    * -0.478    = -0.47824416197

---

**EDIT 2**

> Checking wiht y=0 is not enough as it makes the first term of your
>   equation disapear try with y=0.2 or y=1 and you will see that equation
>   (1) and (3) are different.

**Example 2**
y = 1
W = [-2.9469674,    0.03791044,     0.01467374]
X = [1, 60.1825993862098,   86.3085520954683]
z = WTX = 3.6010506763003
h = sigmoid(z) = 0.973430194479833
log(h) = -0.026929162462656
log(1- h) = -3.62797983876421

(3)
**y *     z  - log(1 + e^z)**
1 * 3.6010 - log(1+ e^-3.6010)  = -0.02692916246392

(1)
**y *  log(h)+(1-y) * log(1-h)**
1 * -0.02692 + 0      * -3.627    = -0.02692916246392

Comment: You are  more likely to get an answer if you type the entire question and define all the parameters involved.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks for the guidance, as per which I have tried to add the equation in its basic form, since I am not aware of uploading the math equations, I rather uploaded the image of the equation.

Comment: Please revise my edit to see if I interpreted your notation correctly.

Comment: What is the value of $p(W_T X)$ ?

Comment: @RobinNicole p(WTX) is the sigmoid function i.e  1 / 1 + e ^ (WTX) . So the value is probability( between 0 and 1)

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks aton, I really need to learn this, makes equations so clear.
Also, In the 3rd equation
**ywx** can be written as: **y WTX** ?

Comment: Checking wiht $y = 0$ is not enough as it makes the first term of your equation disapear try with $y = 0.2$ or $y = 1$ and you will see that equation (1) and (3) are different.

Comment: @RobinNicole Kindly see the **Edit 2** Section
In this case, either y = 0 or y=1 as its a Categorical variable in the data-set (Classification problem of machine learning) , Thanks again

Comment: Totally my bad, the formula is actually correct, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate line (2) to 
$$ \sum_i y_i \log (\frac{1 + \exp( W_T X_i )}{1 + \exp( - W_T X_i )}) - \log (1 + \exp(W_T X_i))$$

Then you factor the numerator of the fraction in the log by $\exp(W_T X_i)$ and you get

$$ \sum_i y_i \log (\exp(W_T X )\frac{1 + \exp(- W_T X_i )}{1 + \exp( - W_T X_i )}) - \log (1 + \exp(W_T X_i))$$

$$ \sum_i y_i \log (\exp(W_T X_i )) - \log (1 + \exp(W_T X_i))$$
$$ \sum_i y_i W_T X_i - \log (1 + \exp(W_T X_i))$$

Comment: So are you suggesting that eq (1) is itself wrong ? or the transformation i.e (3) is wrong and the one you have shared should be an alternative or correct transformation ? 
If so how does this equation be reversed to the (1) equation ?
And Thanks a-lot for the prompt help.

Comment: Kindly elaborate how is **log(exp(WT Xi)) = WT Xi** (am sure am missing some basics of algebra)

Comment: MATH : **log(exp(X)) = exp(log(X)) = X**
Got it finally! Kudos @RobinNicole